# How to change MySQL's ft_min_word_len in Windows?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-indexing

None of the solutions suggested to reduce MySQL's `ft_min_word_len` works for me on Windows 7 Pro.

In Control Panel Services the path to MySQL56 server executable reads `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56` 
Both files at `"C:\windows\my.ini"` and at `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini"` reads

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len = 3
```

In MySQL, the query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ft_min_word_len';` still shows 4!!!

Comment: After changing in the `my.ini` file, do you restarted MySQL service?

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify but of course I restart MySQL after every attempt to change the config files.

Answer (score 0):

My bad!!! I was changing the file at `"C:\Windows\my.ini"` and `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini"` instead of the correct one at `"C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini"` as per the path to MySQL56 server executable which reads `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" MySQL56`.

Now working as expected!

Comment: I assume you also explicitly rebuilt the FT indexes?